# Spring MVC get date from controller to JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, controller

So I have a simple login page, after logging in, I would like to display the date in the page after successful login. I can use scriptlet in JSP but I understand it is bad practice so I want to find an alternate way to do it. I believe using the controller, setup a method that returns the JSP file would be the best way to do it but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. Any help is appreciated!

My controller class

```
public class LoginController {

/*
 *  Map /login to this method 
 *  localhost:8080/spring-mvc/login
 *  spring-mvc -> dispatcher (todo-servlet.xml)
 *  dispatcher detects login url
 *  dispatcher use view resolver to find .jsp file based on String. In this case, login
 *  view resolver locates login.jsp and shows the content to user via http
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
// Mark this method as an actual repsonse back to user
@ResponseBody
public String test() {
    return "Hello, world!";
}

// Only handles get request from the login page
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() { 
    // search through the view resolver for login.jsp
    return "login";
}

// Only handles post request from the login page
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
// @RequestParm grabs query param, it has to have the same name as it states in the jsp
// Model is used to supply attributes to views
// ModelMap has the same functionality has model except it has an addition function where it allows a collection of attributes
public String handleLogin(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password, ModelMap model) {
    // Send name to .jsp 
    // use addAttrible( nameAtJSP, nameInRequestParam ) to check for null
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    model.addAttribute("passWelcome", password);
    return "welcome";   
}

/*
 * @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.POST) public String
 * getDate(@RequestParam String date, ModelMap model) { SimpleDateFormat sdf =
 * new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); date = sdf.format(new Date());
 * model.addAttribute("date", date); return "welcome"; }
 */
```

My welcome.jsp which displays info after successful login

```
<html>
  <head>
   <!-- To add value to param url localhost:8080/?name=alex -->

   <title>Welcome page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%-- ${String} picks up param  --%>
    <div>Current date is ${date}</div>
    Welcome ${name} and your password is ${passWelcome}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `POST` handler, redirect to a `GET` handler. Return your `welcome` view from that `GET` handler.

Create another handler (may be in a separate controller, like `HomeController`):

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHome(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("date", new Date());
    // other attributes

    return "welcome";
}
```

And in the `"/login"` `POST` handler:

```java
return "redirect:/home";
```

#### Further Reading

- [*Post/Redirect/Get*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the code under handleLogin instead and it worked perfectly. By the way, 1 controller only can have 1 get and 1 post request?

Comment: Not necessarily. It can have many `GET` and `POST` handlers. I mentioned 'may be a separate controller' just so that the code becomes cleaner.